# File I/O in C language

Tags: c

I am facing a problem with the function below. I am trying to get data from one location and then search for a specified string. After that I am printing the resulting value.
For the first time it's working fine. If I call the function using a for loop however I am unable to print the buffer value.

```
void parse_data(char *fname,int flag)
{
    char str[30]="&lt;Response&gt;";
    char buffer[1024],temp[1024],temp1[1024];
    int nVal=0;
    FILE *fp;
    int s_pos; //string position in the text
    int c_pos; //char position in the text
    char *string;
    char ccnt; //char count
    long lSize;
    long pos=0;
    int c;
    s_pos = -1;
    c_pos = 0;
    fp=fopen(fname,"r");
    //fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_SET);
    string = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open the file \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        if (c_pos == 0)
        {
            for (ccnt = 1; ccnt <= strlen(str); ccnt++)
            {
                if (!feof(fp))
                {
                    string[ccnt - 1] = getc(fp);
                    if(nVal==1)
                    {
                        buffer[pos++] =   string[ccnt -1];
                    }
                }   //if
            }//for

        }//if
        if (c_pos != 0)
            if (!feof(fp))
            {
                for (ccnt = 0; ccnt <= strlen(str) - 2; ccnt++)
                    string[ccnt] = string[ccnt + 1];
                string[strlen(str) - 1] = getc(fp);
                if(nVal==1){
                    buffer[pos++] =   string[strlen(str) - 1];
                }
            }
        if (strcmp(string, str) == 0)
        {

            strcpy(str,"&lt;/Response&gt;");

            s_pos = c_pos;
            if(nVal==1){
                buffer[pos-strlen(str)]='\0';
                break;
            }
            nVal=1;

        }
        c_pos++;
    }
    if(fp!=NULL)
        fclose(fp);
    //printf("\n The String position is %d=\n",s_pos);
    if(flag==0)
        ParsingString_Inserting_To_DataBase(buffer);
    else if(flag==1)
        printf("The Buffer Value is %s \n",buffer);
}

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char fname[30]="/tmp/gcc_trans.html";
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        parse_data(fname,1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do the same function 3 times with the same parameters? It opens and closes the same file every time, so we'd expect the same result 3 times, assuming the file does not change....

Answer (score 1):

I tried to understand your code and failed. Some comments:

1.Use meaningful variable names. Try `pattern` instead of `str`. Use a better name for `ccnt`, `nVal`

1. Instead of the complex loops, try this approach:

   - Read character by character until you find a `&`
   - Read N bytes and check whether the they are `lt;Response&gt;` where N is the length of the string. If they are, break the loop. If they are not, seek backwards N bytes.
   - Save the current offset on the file
   - Repeat the code above with `&lt;/Response&gt;`. Move this code into a helper function.
   - N = current offset - first offset
   - Allocate buffer with N bytes
   - seek to first offset
   - read N bytes into buffer