# Search a string in file using C language

Tags: c, file

I am getting problem with FILEs concept in C language.

My problem is I have a html file , and that was opened in read mode.

I need to get the data from that file. The acurate is i between the two strings.

The strings are `"<Response>"` and `"</Response>"`.

The text file is shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head><title>



</title></head>

<body>

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="pos_fis_transactions.aspx?trans=14%7c35381192%7c10-10-2011%7c1000.0%7c10-10-2011%7cCASH%7cCREDIT%7cc%7cGCC" id="form1">

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE3NDI1ODEyMjhkZKgy7LmL8WTr+VEeDUOifRqzISfa" />



<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgLEypqSAQKez72pDln9yKosD6kd+LvgBmdrWkYoLk2u" />

    <div>



        <textarea name="txtTransAck" rows="2" cols="20" id="txtTransAck">**&lt;Response&gt;14|245&lt;/Response&gt;**</textarea>



    </div>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

In the above html file, I need to pick the data 14|25.

Comment: show us the code you wrote since here to open your file :)

Comment: Do you have to do this in C, or would you be willing to consider another language such as Perl which has slightly better text parsing capabilities built-in?

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of your previous question: [File I/O in C language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977791/file-i-o-in-c-language), but without the code ? Why not read the answer to the previous question and fix the problems as recommended rather than starting all over again ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are not looking for `<Response>` and `</Response>` but `&lt;Resonse&gt;` and `&lt;/Resonse&gt;` .

If the file is not too big, load it into memory and do a

```
strnstr( loadedFileContent, "&lt;Response&gt;", lengthOfLoadedFileContent );
```

This gives you a char pointer to the first `&` - now add  `strlen( "&lt;Response&gt;" )` to that, and you arive at your content.

Now either you know the length of your content and read it, or search from that position on for the nest & and take the string in between.

hth

Mario